# Salesforce access token get refreshed then how long it will expired again

Tags: oauth, salesforce

I have session timeout setting as 1 hours, and my initial access_token seems timeout around this time. This is excepted.

And after it timeout, i did token refresh and get a new access_token, then i observed this refreshed access_token seems not timeout in 1 hours, even 5~6 hours after, it still not expired.

So is there refresed access_token never expire? Can someone explain more about this?

Answer (score 1):

Refresh token policy is managed from admin side usually and is different from the initial access token. From what you say the setting you have right now for Refresh token is probably 'Refresh token is valid until revoked'.

When you go to your Salesforce org go to Setup -> Manage Connected Apps - find the connection you are looking for and see what policy you have set. You can set it to expire in number of days, based on usage or Immediately.

[image: Refresh Token Policy]

Comment: Unfortunately, the option to never expire the refresh token is now broken.